# pip is unable to find a version of library that does exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, python-tesseract

I tried publishing a library (https://test.pypi.org/project/extractable/0.0.21/
), this has dependencies on other libraries, such as pytesseract (https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/). The latest version of pytesseract is 0.3.10

But when I try `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ extractable==0.0.21` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytesseract~=0.3.10 (from extractable) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.8, 0.2.2)
```

whats wrong? why cant it see the 0.3.10 version

Comment: `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ extractable==0.0.21`

Comment: @evanstjabadi yes thats what I did. Edited my post

Comment: Doesn't installation from test pull [this version of `pytesseract`](https://test.pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)?

Comment: @orhtej2 Youre completely right!

Comment: `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple extractable==0.0.21`